# How to prevent the second publisher to publish on the same topic?

Tags: ros, ros2, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am working with ROS2 in my project and I know ROS/ROS2 is capable to handle multiple publishers and subscribers on the same topic. Due to some limitations in my project, I would like to prevent the second publisher to publish on the same topic. It needs to be kind of one publisher for one topic.

Basically, is it something doable in the ROS environment? If so, is there any option or notification infrastructure that notifies the first publisher or any other node?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371597/how-to-prevent-the-second-publisher-to-publish-on-the-same-topic?/) by [ali ekber celik](https://answers.ros.org/users/8866/ali-ekber-celik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2021-02-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-02-12**:
an observation: you tagged this question as ROS1 and ROS2, spanning multiple distros (noetic&melodic vs. foxy&eloquent). Anything specific this refers to?

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-02-12**:
[twist_mux](http://wiki.ros.org/twist_mux) package does something similar for `geometry_msgs::Twist` messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, the intent of the Publish-Subscrib-Pattern is to allow that. See also the [ROS1 wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/Topics) and the [ROS2 wiki](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Topics/Understanding-ROS2-Topics/#background) for background information.

Note that you could work around that with using the (`getNumPublishers` function)[http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1Subscriber.html#ac98e5ff9790e8e5cc11453948ea128ee] of subscribers (in ROS1 at least) to check if this is actually fine. Even though that would then not allow you to do a `rostopic pub` for testing purposes...

You need to make sure manually, that this requirement is met.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2021-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ali ekber celik](https://answers.ros.org/users/8866/ali-ekber-celik/) on 2021-02-12**:
Thanks for your answer. I will take look at `rclcpp` API more and probably the method you told will help me somehow.

**Comment by [ali ekber celik](https://answers.ros.org/users/8866/ali-ekber-celik/) on 2021-02-15**:
By the way, the corresponding method of `getNumPublishers()` in ROS2 is `count_publishers()`

**Comment by [variable](https://answers.ros.org/users/92857/variable/) on 2022-01-06**:
does `count_publishers()` get the total publishers of a topic, or the number of publishers for a node?